# JavaScript - Waiting/blocking until constructor is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

The JavaScript API that I am creating has the following structure:

```
var engine = new Engine({
    engineName: "TestEngine",
    engineHost: "localhost"
});

// I don't want to proceed to the next line until Engine is fully loaded
// But the following part of the API is immediately called before the above is loaded
engine.startCar(
    "car_name",
    "car_id"
);
```

The "Engine" instance takes a few seconds to load (1-2 seconds). So until then, 
`engine.startCar` should NOT be called.

How do I make internal changes to the constructor ( `new Engine()` ) such that, it doesn't return the instance until it is fully loaded?

Comment: Run it in a callback - for instance, [Promises](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec).

Comment: Or return a promise and add the call to `engine.startCar` as a continuation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a standard problem in JavaScript. Normally it occurs when you make AJAX requests, but timeout-based deferreds have the same basic issue.

jQuery, and most libraries with this sort of issue, solve this problem by having an initial method which returns a "deferred" or "promise" object that can be used to say "when X is done, do Y".

This is best explained by example.  If you do the following in your `Engine` constructor:

```
function Engine(option) {
     var readyDeferred = new $.Deferred();
     this.ready = readyDeferred;
     window.setTimeout(1000, function() {
         readyDeferred.resolve();
     }
}
```

You when you build an engine you can simply do the following:

```
var engine = new Engine({...});
engine.ready.done(function() {
    // start your engines!
});
```

Of course, since times vary on client machines, it'd be even better if you could use some logic other than a `window.setTimeout` to trigger your `readyDeferred.resolve();`.  For instance, you might trigger it when all of your AJAX requests have finished, which would be more predictable than any specific wait time.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
function Engine(options, callback){ 
    this.engineName = options.engineName; 
    this.engineHost = options.engineHost; 

    //Wait for something to finish before calling the callback 
    var me = this; 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        callback(me); 
    }, 1000); 

    this.startCar = function(){
        console.log(this.engineName); 
    }
}; 

var engine = new Engine({ 
    engineName: "TestEngine",
    engineHost: "localhost"
}, function(engine){ 
        //Run callback code 
        engine.startCar(); 
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tnpsfy62/1/

Comment: Are you seriously advocating waiting for an async process using `setTimeout`?

Comment: It's just an example as placeholder for an ajax response. How should we know what he is waiting for, as it wasn't defined in the question?

Comment: What's the problem with setTimeout?  As Kim said it's perfect for a basic example, and moreover the OP literally said that it "takes a few seconds to load (1-2 seconds)".  If they'd said "after the page loads" or "after my AJAX comes back" or something then a good answer would include `$(function(...` or `$.ajax(...).done` ... but since it didn't `setTimeout` seems perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function Engine (params) {  
    console.log("In engine constructor");  
    console.log("In engine constructor - all done");  
    setTimeout(myStartEngine, 100);  
}

var engine = new Engine({
    engineName: "TestEngine",
    engineHost: "localhost"
});

// I don't want to proceed to the next line until Engine is fully loaded  
// But the following part of the API is immediately called before the above is loaded  

function myStartEngine() {
    console.log("Starting engine");

    engine.startCar(
        "car_name",
        "car_id"
    );

    console.log("Starting engine - done");
}
```

Output:

```
In engine constructor    
In engine constructor - all done    
About to start engine    
Starting engine - done
```

Example JSFiddle link is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h5nLjj58/).

Best of luck.